# Unexpected poor performance of SortedDictionary compared with Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I don't understand why the performance of SortedDictionary is approximately 5x slower than Dictionary for setting and retrieving values. I expected inserts and deletes to be slower but not updates or retrieves. I have tested .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.0 release compiled code. An array of random keys was pre-computed to ensure random variations weren't responsible for the differences on random access.

Here are the following scenarios tested.

1. Sequential update of each value using [key] accessor
2. Sequential access of each value using [key] accessor
3. Sequential access of each value using TryGetValue
4. Random access of each value using [key] accessor
5. Random access of each value using TryGetValue

Anyone know why the performance difference?

Please if I am doing something wrong or stupid please point it out.

Sample Code: Simply switch out Dictionary with SortedDictionary to test the difference.

```
    const int numLoops = 100;
    const int numProperties = 30;
    const int numInstances = 1000;

    static void DictionaryBench(int numLoops, int numValues, int numInstances, string[] keyArray)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        double total = 0.0d;

        for (int j = 0; j < numLoops; j++)
        {
            //sw.Start();
            Dictionary<string, object> original = new Dictionary<string, object>(numValues);
            for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
            {
                original.Add(String.Format("Key" + i.ToString()), "Value0:" + i.ToString());
            }
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> collectionList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(numInstances);
            for (int i = 0; i < numInstances; i++)
            {
                collectionList.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>(original));
            }
            sw.Start();
            //Set values on each cloned instance to uniqe values using the same keys
            for (int k = 0; k < numInstances; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
                {
                    collectionList[k]["Key" + i.ToString()] = "Value" + k.ToString() + ":" + i.ToString();
                }
            }

            //Access each unique value
            object temp;
            for (int k = 0; k < numInstances; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
                {
                    temp = collectionList[k]["Key" + i.ToString()];
                }
            }
            //Random access
            //sw.Start();
            for (int k = 0; k < numInstances; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++)
                {
                    collectionList[k].TryGetValue(keyArray[i],out temp);
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            total += sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            sw.Reset();
        }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`SortedDictionary` uses a binary search lookup, which is O(*log* n).
`Dictionary` uses a hashtable, which is O(1).

Therefore, `Dictionary` gives faster lookups.

The difference will be even greater with string keys, which are costly to compare.
A `Dictionary` will only iterate the string twice (or more if there are hash collisions) - once to compute the hashcode, and once to ensure that it's an exact match.  A `SortedDictionary` will iterate the string for *every* comparison.

Comment: I don't know if the dictionary iterates the string twice as you say. In my opinion, it should only iterate once to compute the hashcode if there are no collisions. If there are collisions, it should iterate the one time above, plus the number of collisions minus one. I'm talking about the worst case scenario of course...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's unusual.  [Others have gotten the same results](http://blog.nus.edu.sg/nexus/2009/04/16/performance-of-generics-sorteddictionary-and-dictionary/).

I think it's pretty straightforward why one would be slower than the other.  SortedDictionary is doing more.  It's sorting.  Dictionary isn't, so it's faster.

The only true test of what should and should not be performant, is the test you're performed above.  I don't think you're doing anything wrong here.

Comment: I hope to shortly compare performance of B-Tree-Sorted-Dictionary to SortedDictionary on datasets including more than 1,000,000 objects hoping to speed access performance for finding matching objects of in-memory datasets.  This could get interesting.