# Seek through massive data grouped with multiple keys C#

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, list, dictionary

I want to seek through massive data, grouped with multiple keys, in the fastest way possible.
I have a file with this information but I want to load it in-memory. Memory capacitance is not a problem.

```
key1 | key2 | key3 | key4 | value1 | value2
-----|------|------|------|--------|--------
1    | 1    | 1    | 1    | str    | 20
1    | 1    | 1    | 2    | str    | 20
1    | 1    | 1    | 3    | str    | 20
1    | 1    | 2    | 1    | str    | 20
2    | 1    | 1    | 1    | str    | 20
```

I have looked at some collections but I'm still uncertain :
[image]
http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable

Maybe a multikey dictionary will be better because it avoid a lots of redundancy in the keys.

```
public class MultiKeyDictionary<T1, T2, T3> : Dictionary<T1, Dictionary<T2, T3>>


key1 | key2 | key3 | key4 | value1 | value2
-----|------|------|------|--------|--------
1    | 1    | 1    | 1    | str    | 20
     |      |      | 2    | str    | 20
     |      |      | 3    | str    | 20
     |      | 2    | 1    | str    | 20
2    | 1    | 1    | 1    | str    | 20
```

I will not seek every keys but maybe 50% of them.
I'm open to even insane suggestions.

Comment: Can you materialize multiple copies of the data independently optimized for each search you will do?  Indexed for Key1, indexed for key2, etc...

Comment: Can you be more specific about the concrete queries you need to execute against this data?

Comment: I can split the data by key from left to right but to access key 2 I need first to access key 1. So every right key is in a collection from left key. key4 is in key3 and key3 is in key2...

Comment: Let say my keys are Country -> State -> City -> House. They all from a single key.

Comment: There is a related post with quite a few hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681526/system-collections-generic-dictionary-ultimate-performance What about the size limit of 2GB? Do you need concurrent access? Are your keys unique? It might be worthwhile to parallelize your queries, to partition your data, etc. Lots of possible things to dig into.

Comment: Assuming that a) the keys form a natural hierachy, as their names suggest, b) memory really is no problem and c) you'd be willing to invest in longer loading time for best performance, I would not generate one datastructure but four with 1,2,3 and 4 keys. So I'd go for 4 SortedDictionaries.

Comment: From the benchmark I posted, SortedDictionnary is not good. Also from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376459/unexpected-poor-performance-of-sorteddictionary-compared-with-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a `Tuple` of your keys for the dictionary key and for the value.

```
var bank = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, int, int, int>, Tuple<string, int>>();

bank.Add(Tuple.Create(k1, k2, k3, k4), Tuple.Create("str", 20));
```

Comment: no because if he want's to find matches for only 1 key he cant, you're just combining all the keys into a single key, restricting him to a single key for each record which is not what the question is about.

Comment: @Eluvatar In that case he could just use Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, int>> bank, and have each key point to the same Tuple value

Comment: Key1-4 make a single key. I want to avoid redundancy in keys with something like Dictionary<T1, Dictionary<T2, T3>>... but performance is crucial so...